# Como pegar o html da página após carregar o javascript, utilizando GuzzleHttp

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

Bom dia,

Estou criando um Crawler para que acesse a uma página especifica e em seguida pegue alguns dados específicos da página, porém estou com problemas.

Nesse momento estou tentando realizar um teste no instagram, meu código está da seguinte forma:

```
$client = new Client();

$request = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.instagram.com/user/');

return response()->json( $request->getBody() );
```

Porém, no momento em que vou realizar o print do getBody está retornando vazio `{}`, tentei também acrescentar um segundo parâmetros para obter os dados, da seguinte forma:

```
return response()->json( $request->getBody()->getContents() );
```

Ao utilizar o getContents está me retornando pouco html e o restante javascript, devido a isso acredito que o erro possar estar na forma como estou chamando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você usa o `Guzzle`, o valor retornado por `getBody` é um objeto.

Esse objeto é o `GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream`.

Por padrão a classe `json_encode` costuma trazer resultados confusos quando você tenta serializar um objeto que não implemente a interface mágica `JsonSerialize`.

Porém a classe `GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream` implementa o método `__toString`, que permite um comportamento especial para a classe como a mesma é tratada como string.

O que pode ser feito?

Faça um `cast` do resultado para ver o valor retornado da sua requisição, assim:

```
$client = new Client();

// Pequena correção, 'request' é requisição, 'response' é resposta

$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.instagram.com/user/');

var_dump((string) $response->getBody());
```

É importante lembrar também que o a função `response()->json()` do Laravel tem como finalidade serializar valores para o formato JSON. Provavelmente sua requisição terá como resposta um HTML.

Esteja certo do que você vai fazer com o retorno do `Guzzle`.

Dependendo a situação, pra você, seria necessário fazer apenas isso:

```
 return response((string) $response->getBody());
```

> Ao utilizar o getContents está me retornando pouco html e o restante javascript, devido a isso acredito que o erro possar estar na forma como estou chamando.

Eu não sei o que você está tentando fazer, mas se quer que o Instagram te devolva um `JSON`, talvez fosse necessário você acessar a API do Instagram.

Dê uma olhada nela [aqui](https://www.instagram.com/developer/)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Wallace, vou tentar explicar um pouco minha situação, eu gostaria de acompanhar vários perfis especifico e quando postar uma nota imagem eu consiga trazer o mesmo para o meu sistema, eu utilizei o cast porem o resultado estava errado e em seguida, e observei que é possível obter os dados do html após carregar o js utilizado a configuração "timeout", porém como o instagram utiliza react, o html retornado não contem as imagens publicadas, seria apenas essas informações que gostaria, pela rápida lida na API, notei que é necessário passar um token para obter os dados.

Comment: Sim, precisa passar o token. Seria o jeito mais fácil de você conseguir ter um acesso "legal" ao instagram. O problema de você fazer crawler é que eles podem alterar a página a qualquer momento e você dança. A API já costuma ser versionada. Mas se ainda insistir em fazer um Crawler, talvez você possar usar DomDocument, para acessar o atributo `src` da `<img>`

Comment: Entendi wallace, estou ciente sobre o problema da alteração da página, em relação ao tentar pegar o DomDocument, o que está acontecendo é que o Guzzle mesmo setando um timeout de 5 segundos não está conseguindo obter as imagens, está retornando uma numeração desconhecida no lugar dos atributos '<img>', saberia como resolver isso?

Comment: @HenriqueSouzaGoncalves isso é porque o Instagram deve estar retornando um HTML que usa Javascript para renderizar a página. Não tem uma solução fácil para isso. Já ouvi falar que o Ghost JS resolve isso, mas não posso afirmar com certeza, pois nunca usei

Comment: Certo Wallace, vou verificar sua informação, caso não dê certo terei que optar pela API mesmo, porém vou ficar no aguardo de outras respostas, obrigado pela ajuda Wallace!